# Error: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input when start to run fleet server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, osquery

certificate.cer

[image: 1]

When I use **cat** command to read **certificate.cer** in my Linux RH server. It come out with those **unknown symbol** as mentioned in attached picture instead of human readable language such as:

-----BEGIN CERTICATE-----

uiocudcnysyndw77e3fo7nfdslaccu...

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [CER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690) (or BER or DER) and [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) are different formats. PEM is base64-encoded DER with extra header/footer.

To convert between the former and PEM, use `openssl`:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved. I use "openssl x509 inform der -outform pem -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem"